# strange access.log related to acpache proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, log-files, mod-proxy

It might be simple but i can't understand the meaning of this line

> 171.13.14.46 - - [06/Apr/2019:12:24:44 +0000] "CONNECT 133.130.126.119:43 HTTP/1.1" 302 406 "-" "RPS/HTTP PROXY"

is it something to worry about because i have mod_proxy active and mod_proxy_fcgi and how to avoid this in case it's bad like with fail2ban or something.
note that i can't disable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi because it's related to some http2 needed to be work, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the HTTP client from IP address 171.13.14.46 used your Apache server configured as a proxy to connect to a server at IP address 133.130.126.119 but over port 43 which is not normal HTTP port, but the one for `whois`.

If you do not want your proxy used by everyone (as a proxy is normally reserved for some local traffic, but this has not to be misunderstood by a reverse proxy which on the contrary is open to the public), then you need to configure Apache to restrict its use, based on the client IP or other identifier.

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html:

> You can control who can access your proxy via the  control
>   block as in the following example:
>
> ```
> <Proxy "*">
>      Require ip 192.168.0
> </Proxy>
> ```
>
> For more information on access control directives, see mod_authz_host.
>
> Strictly limiting access is essential if you are using a forward proxy
>   (using the ProxyRequests directive). Otherwise, your server can be
>   used by any client to access arbitrary hosts while hiding his or her
>   true identity. This is dangerous both for your network and for the
>   Internet at large. When using a reverse proxy (using the ProxyPass
>   directive with ProxyRequests Off), access control is less critical
>   because clients can only contact the hosts that you have specifically
>   configured.